# Is JUnit considered a plugin?

Tags: junit

My thought is that "JUnit is a framework for testing java applications and is typically implemented as plugins (to popular IDEs)", but can't it also be considered a standalone testing tool if implemented as a standalone (although it might be a stupid idea)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JUnit is a testing framework.

You would still require a "runner" to run your JUnit tests, be it Maven or a similar.

There are [stand alone runners](http://cloudbees.github.io/junit-standalone-runner/) available so you can execute tests without build tools or an IDE.

Comment: I didn't get the whole concept at the time. Thanks for the answer.